# failed to connect with MySql database on docker

Tags: php, mysql, docker, codeigniter-4

I am trying to connect the CodeIgniter 4 to Mysql on docker but failed, the error message is ***Unable to connect to the database***

The docker.yml file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql/mysql-server:8.0
    ports:
        - "42313:3306"
    volumes: 
      - ./db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123
      MYSQL_DATABASE: dbase
      MYSQL_USER: user1
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: user1
  
  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    restart: always
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: user1
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: user1
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: dbase

  marketplace:
    build: ./mycodeIgnitor
    volumes: 
      - ./mycodeIgnitor:/var/www/html/
    depends_on:
       - db
    restart: always
    links:
      - db:mysql
    ports:
      - "8000:80"

volumes:
    db_data:
```

The database configuration in App/Config/Database in mycodeIgnitor

```
public $default = [
        'DSN'      => '',
        'hostname' => 'localhost',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '123',
        'database' => 'dbase',
        'DBDriver' => 'MySQLi',
        'DBPrefix' => '',
        'pConnect' => TRUE,
        'DBDebug'  => TRUE,
        'cacheOn'  => false,
        'cacheDir' => '',
        'charset'  => 'utf8',
        'DBCollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
        'swapPre'  => '',
        'encrypt'  => false,
        'compress' => false,
        'strictOn' => false,
        'failover' => [],
        'port'     => 3306,
    ];
```

How I connect to the database in my controller file

```
        $db = \Config\Database::connect();
        echo  !$db;
        $query = $db->query('SELECT * FROM wp_users');
        $results = $query->getResult();

        foreach ($results as $row)
        {
                print_r(row);
        }
```

The error message is ***Unable to connect to the database***, please let me know if you're able to spot my mistake. Thank.

Comment: In CI4 there's 2 ways of setting DB config, the `Database.php` file and the `.env` file. Keep in mind that the `.env` file will always takes over the php file. So first thing, take a look at `.env` file and check that DB config is either commented out or not set.

Comment: I've commented out the database config in .env file

Answer (score 0):

okay, I hope this can help others. So, in docker, the names of the services inside the docker-compose.yml become the internal hostname. So, the hostname should be 'db' instead.